# exception error in parse csv file in encog3 java

Tags: java, csv, networking, encog

i am trying to train neural network by encog3 java library ,i use backpropogation algorithm and my dataset is KDD Cup 1999 dataset 10 percently ( provide a completed source for
implementing and testing intrusion detection systems. This
database contains 22 different attacks and normal connections The dataset )
here is some of my code:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork(); 
      network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),true,2)); 
      network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),true,3)); 
      network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(),true,1)); 
      //network.setLogic(new FeedforwardLogic()); 
      network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();  
      network.reset();
    // create training data
       MLDataSet trainingSet = new CSVNeuralDataSet("kddcupupdate.csv", 2, 1, true);
       File f =new File("mytrainset");
       EncogUtility.saveEGB(f, trainingSet);
      // train the neural n
       final Backpropagation train = new Backpropagation(network, trainingSet, 0.7, 0.3);

        int epoch = 1;
          do { 
           train.iteration(); 
           System.out
             .println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + train.getError()); 
           epoch++; 
          } while(train.getError() > 0.01); 

          // test the neural network 
          System.out.println("Neural Network Results:"); 
          for(MLDataPair pair: trainingSet ) { 
           final MLData output = network.compute(pair.getInput()); 
           System.out.println(pair.getInput().getData(0) + "," + pair.getInput().getData(1) 
             + ", actual=" + output.getData(0) + ",ideal=" + pair.getIdeal().getData(0)); 
          }
```

}

when i run this code ,given exception error this :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.encog.util.csv.CSVError: Error:Unparseable number: "tcp" on [tcp], decimal:.,sep: ,
at org.encog.util.csv.CSVFormat.parse(CSVFormat.java:191)
at org.encog.util.csv.ReadCSV.getDouble(ReadCSV.java:312)
at org.encog.ml.data.buffer.codec.CSVDataCODEC.read(CSVDataCODEC.java:215)
at org.encog.ml.data.buffer.MemoryDataLoader.external2Memory(MemoryDataLoader.java:89)
at org.encog.ml.data.specific.CSVNeuralDataSet.<init>(CSVNeuralDataSet.java:111)
at org.encog.ml.data.specific.CSVNeuralDataSet.<init>(CSVNeuralDataSet.java:77)
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? The error looks pretty self-explainatory... ?

Comment: why it give exception when i run my code up,although when i try other dataset sush as xor dataset ,do not  any exception ?  @RadiRadichev

Comment: It's reading a string where it expects a decimal from the looks of it. Can you post a line of your input csv file and the class you're trying to parse into?

Comment: so that second element, for some reason your parser expects it to be a decimal. I'm not sure how you configure it, I assume it's in the CSVNeuralDataSet class. Can you paste that?

Comment: this is a line of my input csv file : 0,tcp,http,SF,181,5450,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,8,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,9,9,1.00,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,normal           and i use two method "saveEGB" and "loadCSV2memory" in "EncogUtility" class  like here: https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/encog/util/simple/EncogUtility.java  @RadiRadichev

Comment: Well as I said, the input csv and your target class differ so it's unable to map the second field ('tcp') in this case and crashes. This happens when you are creating the CSVNeuralDataSet so inspect that. I would put a breakpoint at line 77 in that class and follow through with debugger to see exactly where it breaks. I can't help you much without being able to see the CSVNeuralDataSet at least.